# sqrt not returning correct values in C++

Tags: visual-c++

I have been working on this homework problem for about 6 hours.

We are given a volume in gallons, and have to find the radius and diameter of a cylinder (the pond). I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. cmath is included in my program. Here is the code:

```
1  //dblPondRadius = sqrt((dblPondVolumeCube)/M_PI*11));
2    
3  dblPondVolumeCube = static_cast<double(intPondVolume)*.13368;
4    
5  dblPondRadius = dblPondVolumeCube/(M_PI*11);
6    
7  dblPondRadius = sqrt (dblPondVolumeCube);
8    
9  dblPondDiameter = dblPondRadius*2;
```

Line 3 converts the gallons into cubic feet
Line 5 is step 1 of the pond radius formula that was given to us (see formula in the comment at top of code)
Line 7 is step 2 of the formula
Line 9 computes the diameter

The whole rest of the program is dependent on calculations from the diameter. It's due in 1.5 hours please help!!!

Comment: It sounds like you don't have the right prototype.  After including `cmath`, you should be using `std::sqrt`.  Does `sqrt("a")` give an error at least?

Answer (score 0):

Line 5 sets `dblPondRadius`, then line 7 sets it again, without reference to the previous value, so line 5's work is thrown away.

Comment: I tried putting it all on one line, and still didn't get it right. I had it like this: dblPondRadius = sqrt((dblPondVolumeCube)/M_PI*11));

Comment: I even tried plugging in a simple number, like, 4, and it returned the sqrt of 4 as 4.

Comment: I tried adding std::sqrt just now, no change. And no, it's not giving an error, it's just not computing the square root.